# Declaring variable outside a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

sender_psid is declared inside the app.post function. Is there a way to declare it gobally so that the function calls at the bottom can access it?

Note: Declaring it outside the function wouldn't help, as webhook.event does not exist outside it.

```
/ Creates the endpoint for our webhook
app.post('/webhook', (req, res) => {

  let body = req.body;

  // Checks this is an event from a page subscription
  if (body.object === 'page') {

    // Iterates over each entry - there may be multiple if batched
    body.entry.forEach(function(entry) {

    // Gets the body of the webhook event
    let webhook_event = entry.messaging[0];
    console.log(webhook_event);


    // Get the sender PSID
    let sender_psid = webhook_event.sender.id;
    console.log('Sender PSID: ' + sender_psid);

    // Check if the event is a message or postback and
    // pass the event to the appropriate handler function
    if (webhook_event.message) {
      msg.handleMessage(sender_psid, webhook_event.message);
    } else if (webhook_event.postback) {
      msg.handlePostback(sender_psid, webhook_event.postback);
    }


  });

    // Returns a '200 OK' response to all requests
    res.status(200).send('EVENT_RECEIVED');
  } else {
    // Returns a '404 Not Found' if event is not from a page subscription
    res.sendStatus(404);
  }

});
//Imports functions from other files
let  msg = require('./msg.js'),
     handleMessage = msg.handleMessage(sender_psid, received_message),
     handlePostback = msg.handlePostback(sender_psid, received_postback),
     callSendAPI = msg.callSendAPI(sender_psid, response);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You NEVER want global variables that are request-specific in node.js servers.  This just allows different requests to trounce the values that other requests are trying to use.  If your request handlers have any asynchronous operations in them, this would be a form of concurrency bug or race condition.  Do not do it.  Do not try to do it.  It's a bad design.

Instead, you have these options:

1. Pass any data from your request handler as a function argument to the external function.
2. Add the data as a property to the `req` or `res` object (which is always request-specific) and then pass that `req` or `res` object to your external function so it can access the data there.
3. Add the data as a property to some other object that you create specifically in that request handler and then pass that object to your external function so it can access the data there.

If you are trying to create some data in a request handler that you then want access to in some future request handler, then you would either use a cookie or a session to be able to save that data and then get access to it in a future request from that same client.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how I can pass the data to the function. I want the external function calls to be global.@jfriend00

Comment: @Rashik - I don't follow what you're trying to do to be more specific with code.  The key concept you have to start with is that a typical server is meant to server the requests of many, many users.  So, you can never take some data  from a request that is related to a specific user, stick it into a global variable and then reliably use it somewhere else.  If you're going to stick user-specific data somewhere, you have to stick it in a user-specific object (such as a cookie, a session, the user's database record, etc...).  Then, when you need that data again, you look it up based on the user.

Comment: @Rashik - So, for me to help more specifically, you will have to show a lot more detail in both code and words about exactly what you're trying to do.  Right now, you see to have a variable within a request called `sender_psid` which appears to be specific to one user.  There can presumably be many of those different users so it's unclear how you have any idea which of those you want to use elsewhere and when.

Comment: @jfriend- This is the index.js file for a messenger-bot.

Comment: @jfriend-I have added more details. The sender_psid is a parameter for all three of my external functions. As you can see two of those functions are called inside app.post. So, when I try to declare those functions I am getting an error as sender_psid is not declared globally.

Comment: @Rashik -  Still not enough information.  I can see that `sender_psid` arrives in the body of a POST, but I don't know what it is or what you're trying to do with it.  Do you get that you can't capture something in a POST and use it at server initialization time (that's what your current code appears to be trying to do).  You haven't been sent that info yet when you're trying to use it.  Furthermore than info is probably only related to one specific user and you could have lots of users doing the same thing.

Comment: @jfriend-  The PSID is used by a Messenger bot to identify a person when sending messages. It is being passed into the functions which process and reply to the messages sent by the user.

Comment: @Rashik - Do you get that the `sender_psid` arrives some time in the future when a POST request arrives from some specific user.  So, the ONLY place you can use that value is inside that POST request handler or in some function you call from inside that request handler.  If you want to register something for that `sender_psid`, then you must call a function from within your POST handler to do that and pass it the `sender_psid`.  There is no other way.

Comment: @Rashik - You also have to make sure if you get multiple POST requests from the same user that you aren't accumulating duplicate listeners or bots or whatever it is you're configuring because the same user can do multiple POST requests fairly easily.